# How to get the parameter n its values from action to JSP in Struts2

Tags: parameters, struts2

I have action like below in struts.xml

defaultPage
        defaultPage

I want to redirect control to same page along with few parameters depending on the result from the method "sentMailToContactUs"

Ex:

if sentMailToContactUs return success/Fail

```
<result name="success" type="redirctAction">
<param name ="actionName">Contact</param>
<param name ="resultRtn">Y</param>
</result>

    <result name="fail" type="redirctAction">
<param name ="actionName">Contact</param>
<param name ="resultRtn">N</param>
</result>
```

How to read the above parameter from action in JSP...........?

If parameter resultRtn = 'Y'  --> Some controls are available

If parameter resultRtn = 'Y'  --> Some controls are not available,

If parameter resultRtn = 'null'  --> Show all Controls

Thank you......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it worked something like this..

In struts.xml:

```
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">
     <param name="actionName">Contact</param>
     <param name="resultVariable">${resultVariable}</param>
</result>
```

In action Class getter Setter for `resultVariable`

In Contact page to receive parameter n its value:

```
<s:set var="reaultTyp"><s:property value="%{#parameters['resultVariable']}"/></s:set>
```

thank you both....

Comment: Thanks, this work for me. I was using <s:property value="resultVariable"/> with no success!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a **set** method for `resultRtn` in your `Contact` action to set the 'Y', 'N' or other values.  And you need to have a **get** method for your JSP to call so that you can retrieve the value and display the controls accordingly.

Comment: Param tags in a result configuration are set on the result, not on the action. In the case above, Struts2 would call the `setActionName` method and attempt to call the `setResultRtn` method on `ServletActionRedirectResult` for which the latter doesn't exist. Once he is successfully appending resultRtn=Y/N to the URL, then your answer would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The `param` tag is not for setting parameters on the URL, its for setting configuration parameters for the result. You should be able to set the query string parameters within the `actionName` as follows:

```
<result name="success" type="redirctAction">
    <param name="actionName">Contact?resultRtn=Y</param>
</result>

<result name="fail" type="redirctAction">
    <param name="actionName">Contact?resultRtn=N</param>
</result>
```

You can also use a normal redirect in place of a redirectAction here.